# Google Drive api revisions information null

Tags: google-drive-api, revisions

When I tried to get the information about the last user that has modified an specifific revision or the size of the revision, the result is null.

I dont know why, but this happens to me with the type of files: mimeType: `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`, `application/vnd.google-apps.document`... However, I get all the information with mimeType: `application/msword`.

Could someone help me???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Revision information is not the same for Google Docs types, i.e. the ones you mention, sorry.